# Проблема со значением переменной в аналоге программы "Крестики-Нолики" (Python)

Tags: python, ооп

Обычная программа "Крестики-Нолики" на Python. Все прекрасно работает за исключением одного НО.

Класс игры (Game) имеет очки игроков (self.scores) в виде словаря, а также метод класса, который принимает игрока, который одержал победу и увеличивает количество его очков на 1. Вывод очков производится после каждой игры. При этом значения словаря, предназначенного для очков, не обновляются, а в чем заключается суть ошибки так и не пойму.

(Если будут советы касательно других аспектов кода, буду весьма признателен)

Вот весь код:

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, num_cell, status):
        self.status = status
        self.num_cell = num_cell

    def __str__(self):
        return f"'{self.num_cell}': {self.status}"


class Board:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = {}

    def print_status_board(self):
        """Отображает текущее состояние игровой доски"""
        game_board = f"| {self.board[1]} | {self.board[2]} | {self.board[3]} |" \
                     f"\n-------------" \
                     f"\n| {self.board[4]} | {self.board[5]} | {self.board[6]} |" \
                     f"\n-------------" \
                     f"\n| {self.board[7]} | {self.board[8]} | {self.board[9]} |"
        print(f"Текущее состояние игрового поля: \n{game_board}")

    def new_board(self):
        """Создает новую чистую доску для новой игры"""
        for num in range(1, 10):
            cell = Cell(num, " ")
            self.board[cell.num_cell] = cell.status

    def valid_move_try(self, position):
        """Проверяет свободна ли ячейка игровой доски"""
        if self.board[int(position)] == " ":
            return True
        return False

    def change_board(self, position, var_type):
        """Видоизменяет игровую доску"""
        if self.valid_move_try(position):
            self.board[int(position)] = var_type
            return self.board
        return None

    def win_combinations(self, player):
        """Возвращает TRUE если игрок провел одну из выигрышных комбинаций"""
        if (self.board[1] == player.var_type and self.board[2] == player.var_type and self.board[3] == player.var_type) or \
        (self.board[4] == player.var_type and self.board[5] == player.var_type and self.board[6] == player.var_type) or \
        (self.board[7] == player.var_type and self.board[8] == player.var_type and self.board[9] == player.var_type) or \
        (self.board[1] == player.var_type and self.board[4] == player.var_type and self.board[7] == player.var_type) or \
        (self.board[2] == player.var_type and self.board[5] == player.var_type and self.board[8] == player.var_type) or \
        (self.board[3] == player.var_type and self.board[6] == player.var_type and self.board[9] == player.var_type) or \
        (self.board[1] == player.var_type and self.board[5] == player.var_type and self.board[9] == player.var_type) or \
        (self.board[3] == player.var_type and self.board[5] == player.var_type and self.board[7] == player.var_type):
            return True
        return False


class Player:
    def __init__(self, var_type):
        self.var_type = var_type

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.var_type}"


class Game:
    GAME_STATUSES = ["Ничья", "Победитель"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.player1 = Player("X")
        self.player2 = Player("O")
        self.board = Board()
        self.scores = {self.player1.var_type: 0, self.player2.var_type: 0}

    @staticmethod
    def welcome_game():
        """Приветствует игрока и выводит инструкции к игре"""
        print("Добро пожаловать в игру 'Крестики - нолики'".center(100, "_"))
        print(
            "ВАША ЗАДАЧА - ВЫСТАВИТЬ В РЯД 3 ФИГУРЫ ДЛЯ ПОБЕДЫ!".center(
                100, "-")
        )
        print("Пример игрового поля с номерами позиций клеток".center(100, " "))
        print("""
                                        -------------------
                                        |  1  |  2  |  3  |
                                        -------------------
                                        |  4  |  5  |  6  |
                                        -------------------
                                        |  7  |  8  |  9  |
                                        -------------------
                        """)

    def change_turn(self, player):
        """Меняет ход между игроками"""
        if player is self.player1:
            return self.player2
        else:
            return self.player1

    def modify_board(self, position, var_type):
        """Изменяет игровую доску"""
        if self.board.change_board(position, var_type) is not None:
            return self.board.change_board(position, var_type)
        else:
            position = input("Ход недоступен. Попробуйте ещё раз!\n==> ")
            return self.board.change_board(position, var_type)

    def one_game_move(self, player):
        """Один ход в процессе игры"""
        self.board.print_status_board()
        player_position = input(f"Очередь игрока - '{player}'! Выберите номер ячейки для хода.\n==> ")
        self.modify_board(player_position, player.var_type)
        if self.board.win_combinations(player):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def score_up(self, player):
        """Увеличивает кол-во очков победителя"""
        self.scores[player.var_type] += 1

    @staticmethod
    def one_game():
        """Запускает одну игру"""
        game = Game()
        game_player = game.player1
        game.welcome_game()
        game.board.new_board()
        count = 9
        while count > 0:
            count -= 1
            if game.one_game_move(game_player):
                print(f"'{game_player}' - {Game.GAME_STATUSES[1]}!")
                game.score_up(game_player)
                break
            else:
                game_player = game.change_turn(game_player)
        if count == 0:
            print(f"{Game.GAME_STATUSES[0]}. Игра окончена!")

my_game = Game()
while True:
    my_game.one_game()
    end_game_question = None
    while end_game_question not in ("y", "n"):
        end_game_question = input("\nХотите закончить игру? (Введите y - ДА, n - НЕТ)\n==> ").lower()
    print(f"-------------------------"
          f"\n|    'X'    |    'O'    |"
          f"\n-------------------------"
          f"\n|     {my_game.scores['X']}    |      {my_game.scores['O']}     |"
          f"\n-------------------------\n")
    if end_game_question == "y":
        print("\nИгра 'Крестики - Нолики' закончилась!")
        break
    elif end_game_question == "n":
        print("\nПродолжаем игру!")
```

Comment: В каждой новой игре игроки создаются заново. Потому и счётчик обнуляется.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!